# How to read a list of html tables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, pandas

I have a list of HTML tables given by pandas data frame in the format of:

```
list_html = 
[<table border="1" class="dataframe">
 <thead>
<tr style="text-align: right;">
  <th></th>
  <th>score</th>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>name</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
<tr>
   <th>0</th>
  <td>0.776959</td>
  <td>grade</td>
  <td>grade</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <td>0.414527</td>
  <td>class</td>
  <td>class</td>
</tr>, ... , ... ]
```

I am trying to visualize this data in an html page and could not do it. I do not have enough experience in web development. My goal is to use JavaScript to loop through each item the list and visualize them below each  other in html. It would be great if anybody can help!

This is what I tried so far, its probably completely wrong:

```
var list_html = list_html  // list of html codes as a      javascript variable.
var arrayLength = analysis.length;
for (var i in list_html) {
  document.getElementById("analysis_1").innerHTML = list_html[i];
}
```

Comment: What is `list_analysis`, `analysis` and `tone_analysis` ?? I don't see any relationship between these objects

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to edit right that part. just put it in the correct format @Pugazh

Comment: You're apparently missing the close tag for the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a valid array of strings `list_html` (actually `list_html` is not a valid array of strings, since the markup in each entry is not wrapped in quotes) and a container in the DOM with id "`analysis_1`" it's simply a matter of:

```
var container = document.getElementById('analysis_1');
for (var i = 0; i < list_html.length; i++) {
    container.innerHTML += list_html[i];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

well... in your scenario there is no need at all for a loop, you can simply inject a single string by joining the elements in the array:

```
document.getElementById('analysis_1').innerHTML = list_html.join('');
```

fast and simple! :)

Comment: I might be tempted to wrap each table in a div ... something like ... `var div = document.createElement("div"); div.id = "table_"+i; container.appendChild(div); div.innerHTML = list_html[i];`

Comment: it's unnecessary and moreover slower than just inject a string into the DOM... elements creation and manipulation are very expensive! Instead if you want to wrap with a div you could do this:  `container.innerHTML += '<div>' + list_html[i] + '</div>';`

Comment: Could you point me to some documentation that discusses this expense difference please?  A quick experiment in Chrome shows little difference in timing.  Injecting HTML is perhaps 5% faster over 50,000 iterations.

Comment: Well... my sentence is based on years of experience (when chrome did not exists, IE was a nightmare and no js framework were available), but maybe nowadays is not that important :P

Comment: There is still a difference in timing, even if it's small, but it seems counter intuitive.  I would have thought string injection would be more expensive since it needs to create elements plus parse a string.  Very intriguing

Answer (score -1):

using [jquery's selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :

1. Give the 'td' which contains the data a class name, eg: 'MyTd';
2. Select them all: $(.MyTd).text()
3. Done!

Comment: This answer does not seem to go with this question